# how to use bs4 to get to a link nested within a matched div element

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Is there any way to get a the link out of an `a` element that's nested within a `div` element when all I can match is the `div` element? Something similar to the `get_text()` method but for links.

Here is what i have matched:

```
<div class="headline"><a href="http://www.davar1.co.il/116053/">כל שעה שווה לכם קצת יותר</a>
```

this is my bs4 call:

```
>>> headlines = davarsoup.select('.headline')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! i thought i had tried this solution already, but apparently there was a typo. here is how i solved it:

```
>>> headlines = davarsoup.select('.headline > a')
```

sorry to bother anyone who might have bothered.